# Getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' while import React from "react"

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new in React JS. While I try to run a simple react application it shows an error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'.

My package.json is like this

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  }
```

And config.js is

```
var DIST_DIR=path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");
var SRC_DIR=path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

var config= {
    entry:
        SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    mode:"development",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.js?/,
                include:SRC_DIR,
                loader:"babel-loader",
                query:{
                    presets:["es2015","es2016","env","react","stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};


module.exports=config;
```

index.js is like

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";

class App extends  React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>,window.document.getElementById("apps"));
```

This question asked before and I tried all the suggested ways but still getting this error.Please help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: This is not enough can you please share some other files where you have written some react code.

Comment: @VinitRaj updated

Comment: its a. very famous error in starters den ! buddy! I had the same I solved it using 
Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD).
read it here 
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd/

Comment: Your code seems to be right ,may be webpack version is creating problem,just try to use earlier version of webpack,you can use following dependencies:-`babel-core,babel-loader,babel-preset-es2015,babel-preset-react,babel-preset-stage-1,webpack@3.5.3,webpack-dev-server` and .babelrc which will contain following :- `{
 "presets":["react","es2015","stage-1"]
}`